# Python Tkinter Radiobutton variable output

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to find a way to take the value from a Radiobutton, set it to a variable, and use the variable outside the class in other parts of my code. Heres a sample of my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.v1 = IntVar()

        Label(master, text="""Which Method?""",justify = LEFT, padx = 20).pack()
        Radiobutton(master, text="Positive",padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Negative", padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Both", padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=3).pack(anchor=W)
```

Is there a way, preferably without use definitions and the command option, to set a variable "Method" to the value that the user selected? And then use that value outside the class.

I tried using Method=self.v1.get() but that didn't work.

Comment: Can't you just access it with `w.v1.get()` outside of your class? (Assuming that `w` is the name of the `Window` instance)

Comment: What does "that didn't work" mean? What happened? That's exactly how you get a value from a `IntVar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.v1 = IntVar()

        Label(master, text="""Which Method?""",justify = LEFT, padx = 20).pack()
        Radiobutton(master, text="Positive",padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Negative", padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Both", padx = 20, variable=self.v1, value=3).pack(anchor=W)

root = Tk()
w = Window(root)
w.master.mainloop()

print "The radiobutton outside of the class: %d" %w.v1.get()
```

Here is an example of what I mean in my comment. My example should print the `value` of whichever `Radiobutton` is currently selected when you close the window.

In your case, depending on whichever value the `Radiobutton` has, you would decide which functions to call.